# Xamarin.Android: Can not debug

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have a problem with Visual Studio Community 2015 and Xamarin.

When I want to debug my Program the virtual device start but the App does not open.

This is the Log:

```
1>"aapt.exe" exited with code -1073741819.
1>The file "obj\Debug\android\bin\packaged_resources" does not exist.
```

I don´t know how to fix this problem, I hope you can help me.

Complete Log: [Here](http://pastebin.com/5irdxk5W)

Comment: Are you using resources? The filenames cannot have a - character in them for some reason. Check that. If that doesn't work check out [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/63356/the-file-obj-debug-android-bin-packaged-resources-does-not-exist) forum link for more help

Comment: @GeraldVersluis I already found this Post. But it does not help me. I do not have a - in any ressources. The other solution with the right SDKs is also not possible because it is outdated.

Comment: What do you mean by 'it is outdated?' What is outdated? And what makes you think it is outdated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue currently, where a too new version of Android SDK Build-tools. This error will occur when version 24.x is used, due to Xamarin being compatible with 23.x

We have a technical bulletin available on our release blog, which describes the issue and the solution:

> Recommended fix: Uninstall Android SDK Build-tools version 24 using
>   the Android SDK Manager.
>
> Another separate issue is that version 24 of the Android SDK
>   Build-tools package requires Java JDK 1.8 or higher. This can cause at
>   least 1 error:
>
> “java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main :
>   Unsupported major.minor version 52.0”

Source: https://releases.xamarin.com/technical-bulletin-android-sdk-build-tools-24/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few solutions that worked for some users, as this error might have multiple causes :

- Check your AndroidManifest.xml file for any typo. File names must not contain characters like -. This is also the case for any code file. Oh, and by the way, don't use keywords as file names. For example, a file named New.cs might break your app.
- Check that the Android SDK you're targeting is installed on your computer. Click Tools->Android->Package manager and install or update the SDK you're targeting. Also, install tools, build tools and platform tools. You might want Android Support Library and Google Play Services too.

According to the logs you put on pastebin, it seems like the last thing done before the build fail is to check for Android SDK Build tools rev 24. There is high chances you lack those files, or that some are corrupted. I'd delete and reinstall everything.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already searched for a typo but can´t find any. I also installed everything that was avaible in the SDK Manager but nothing helped.

Comment: Then check if you have Preview Build tools installed, (Build Tools rev. 24). If so, delete them and install the latest 23.x version of the build tools.